# Imsave changes the color of an image if converted using numpy and scipy.misc.pilutil

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I have some problems with a simple image processing task. The code looks like this:

```
from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread, imsave
import numpy as np

infile = imread('in.png')
outfile = np.multiply(infile, 1.0).astype(int)    # Just an example of array manipulation

print type(infile) == type(outfile)        # True

# Exactly the same
print infile
print outfile


imsave('out.png', outfile)
```

This produces an array with different grayscale colors than the input image. It magically works if I change the manipulation to be `outfile = np.multiply(infile, 1)` (with an int instead of a float).

Can someone explain to me what I don't understand? The input image is a greyscale image.

Comment: Could you show `infile.dtype` and `infile.max()`?  Note that `imsave` always saves the file using an 8 bit format.

Comment: `infile.dtype` is uint8 and `infile.max()` is 178